# Eclipse/Aptana Subprojects

Tags: eclipse, aptana

I've been using a eclipse with the aptana plugin and have all my projects neatly defined.

However one project is a main corporate website lets say http://sun.com and it's set up nicely for FTP transfers.

However i was wondering if there was a way to define directories of that as subprojects or projects in there own right without messing up the file transfer stuff.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe creating project inside any folder of the main project?

Comment: I thought of that but not sure if changes here will confict with the copy sitting in the main folder when I do a svn commit.

I can add a ignore for them because then the subproject would also respect this.

Comment: Do you have any sample Java script work which is built using the Aptana, if yes can you please share with me, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse projects can't have sub-projects:

[How to setup an Eclipse Project with multiple Subprojects (OSGi-Bundles)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616746/how-to-setup-an-eclipse-project-with-multiple-subprojects-osgi-bundles)

However, as the poster suggested there, you could have a different workspace where each of the sub-directories was defined as its own project. You would have to switch between the two workspaces, but that may not be an onerous workflow depending on the situation.