# How to setup an Eclipse Project with multiple Subprojects (OSGi-Bundles)

Tags: java, eclipse, build-process, build, osgi

[Sherlog](http://sherlog.javakontor.org/gs-getting-sherlog) is an OSGi-based log analyzer, if I import this project as an  workspace snapshot I receive lot's of projects in my workspace, but I would prefere to have them as subprojects in a project.

The other option would be to checkout from svn, but then I face other problems (I don't know how to setup the dependencies for automatically build)

Does anyone have an idea or good links on this topic? Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

EDIT: For Eclipse 4.5 and newer please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34134833/53897

---

Eclipse does not support subprojects.  The Eclipse way of life is one or more projects in a workspace (perhaps using work sets to avoid seeing them all).

As a consequence we have established an approach where we switch workspaces when switching projects.  Team Projects are nice for this for CVS.  For git I do a separate clone for each workspace as the Maven support in Eclipse does not pick up changes in the pom hierarchy (like a new project) easily.

Comment: +1 Thanks, this project already uses Team Project Set Files. These are the keywords to I've to google

Comment: Since Eclipse 4.5/Mars, this answer is out-of-date, because Eclipse supports nested project view: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.5/M5/#nested-projects

Comment: Great - glad to hear that this has gotten better in the 5.5 years that has passed since I originally answered the question.  Actually I thought that Eclipse has but in name entered maintenance mode.

Comment: @Mickael instead of commenting and downvoting you should consider writing a better and more up-to-date answer.

Comment: @Thorbjørn: It would be more efficient if you update your answer, and I'll vote it up. SO readers tend to read only the highest ranked answer marked as resolved (fair enough). Unfortunately, writing new answers on that thread wouldn't make readers read it.

Comment: @Thorbjørn: I know it's not how SO is intended to work, but it's how I've seen user using it. And I care more about users than about SO principles ;) Thanks for your edit anyway!

Comment: @Mickael I think you should bring that up on meta then.

Answer (score 3):

As of Eclipse 4.5 (starting from Mars M5) subprojects are supported.
Either import a multi module maven project like [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/reactor.html).

Or create a directory structure like this.

```
BaseProj
----.project
----JavaSubProject1
--------.project
--------.classpath
--------src
--------JavaSubProject2
------------.project
------------.classpath
------------src
```

Use 'File->Import->Existing Projects into Workspace' and import only BaseProj. It will import all projects.
Be sure to activate hierarhical view in Project Explorer.

Later edit - When using import dialog, check 'Search for nested projects' otherwise only BaseProj will be created.

Comment: I would like this to prevent ex.: sub-project1 from having access to sub-project2, but sub-project2 can see everything from sub-project1, is it possible? also, last time I tried eclipseMars it was so glitchy that I was forced back into eclipseLuna; should I try eclipseNeon or it is too risky? :)